# Restrict access per customer in django

Tags: python, django, security, access-control

I am trying to restrict access to records based on each customer so users can't access each others data through URL. I have added this but its restricting everything.

```
    if request.user.customer != Infringement.customer:
            return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!')"
```

views.py

```
        @login_required(login_url='login') 
        def infringement(request, pk):   
           if request.user.customer != Infringement.customer:
            return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!')
        infringement = Infringement.objects.get(id=pk)    
        notes = infringement.note_set.all().order_by('-created')
          if request.method == "POST":
           note = Note.objects.create(
           customer=request.user.customer,
           user = request.user,
           infringement = infringement,
           body=request.POST.get('body')
       )    
       return redirect('infringement', pk=infringement.id)
 
     context= {'infringement': infringement, 'notes': notes}    return
     render(request, 'base/infringements.html', context)
```

Comment: also tried this. Seems better but still doesnt work.                                                               
    if request.user.customer != Infringement.objects.get(id=pk):
        return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!')

Comment: Are you intending to
`
       infringement = Infringement.objects.get(id=pk)    

      if request.user.customer != infringement.customer:
       return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!')
`
and then perhaps compare the id's of the objects rather than the objects themselves.

Comment: I am trying to write if the logged in users customer field does not equal to the records customer field, say your are not allowed here.  customer is a fk in both users model and infringement model.

Comment: @charlie I was wondering if you can help me with me other question. Really stuck. Thanks

Comment: I'll try, what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@login_required(login_url='login') 
def infringement(request, pk):   
      infringement = Infringement.objects.get(id=pk)
      if request.user.customer.id != infringement.customer.id:
          return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!')
```